# How to wait for WCF proxy client to be ready?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm trying to figure out how to get my WCF proxy class to wait to be ready before proceeding, or allowing calls to the service.

I tried something like this:

```
    _proxy = new WCFBlackjack(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/blackjack/IWCFBlackjack"));

    while(!_proxy.State.Equals(CommunicationState.Opened)) {
        if(!_proxy.State.Equals(CommunicationState.Opening)) {
            try {
                _proxy.Open();
            } catch(EndpointNotFoundException enfe) {
                /* ... */
            }
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
```

But obviously that doesn't work otherwise I wouldn't be here. At first it seems to work but the ChannelFactory throws an InvalidOperationException on the open statement.

I'm new to WCF and maybe I'm thinking too much along the lines of something that is Sockets-esque but I would like my client to continue to retry until the endpoint becomes available or can be found, and somehow fire an on-connected event or something along those lines.

Comment: Ran a test with service hosted or not and the state after the new is "created" regardless if the service is up.  If the service is up then it has a state of Open after the first method call (but not before).

Comment: I have also noticed that if you set a breakpoint before _proxy.Open(), look at inner members of _proxy and then allow the code to continue and run Open, the last will return InvalidOperationException. Looks like this is because debugger evaluates some properties which cause side effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the EndpointNotFoundException, you're probably seeing a message that looks something like, "There was no endpoint listening at...".  What is happening is that during your while loop, you open the proxy on the first pass, handle the error, and then on the second pass you get the InvalidOperationException that says, "The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be modified while it is in the Opened state."

If you abort the connection on the existing proxy, you will not be able to use it for communication going forward.  Once you close the connection, the proxy object will be disposed of. The solution is to close the existing proxy and create a new one.  I have updated your code below:

```
_proxy = new WCFBlackjack(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/blackjack/IWCFBlackjack"));

while(!_proxy.State.Equals(CommunicationState.Opened)) {
    if(!_proxy.State.Equals(CommunicationState.Opening)) {
        try {
            _proxy.Open();
        } catch(EndpointNotFoundException enfe) {
            /* ... */
            _proxy.Abort();
            _proxy = new WCFBlackjack(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/blackjack/IWCFBlackjack"));
        }
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! One note though is that I had to change _proxy.Close(); to _proxy.Abort(); otherwise it'd give me an exception about being unable to change the state.